# How to reset CSS webkit animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I add and remove my class accordingly but for some reason the animation will not reset in Firefox browser.

It seems to me that the animation on before and after is not resetting, so it won't start again.

Does anyone know how I might fix this?
Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBRVjq

```
window.onload = init;

function init() {
  document.getElementById("sendDoxm").onclick = addMyClass;
}

function addMyClass() {
  var classString = this.className;
  var newClass = classString.concat(" clicked"); 
  this.className = newClass; 

  window.setTimeout(function () {
  document.querySelector("#sendDoxm").classList.remove("clicked")

    }, 2500);
}
```

Problem only occurs in Firefox